# Scala Lift - REST-Get on dynamic generated image

Tags: scala, lift

I use Scala and Lift for REST web-services and I have a method that generates dynamic jpg images that should be made accessible via a Get Request, so that for each Get-Request the method generates an image again and sends it back in the response.

I made a case in serve:

```
case "img.jpg" :: Nil Get _ => Full(OkResponse())
case _ => Full(NotFoundResponse())
```

But this case does not seem to be recognised, it always catches the Default-Case.

What is the proper way to serve routes on a *.* url? And what response type can be used to deliver the jpg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file extension is handled separately from the rest of the path, so matching as you do above won't work. You can see some more discussion about this in the [Lift Cookbook](http://cookbook.liftweb.net/#MissingSuffix).

To make the above work, you should be able to do this:

```
case "img" :: Nil Get req if req.path.suffix == "jpg" => Full(OkResponse())
```

I believe you can also use the `Req` object, which will let you specify the suffix like this:

```
case Req("img" :: Nil, "jpg", GetRequest) => Full(OkResponse())
```